# Attempted to update or delete an entity that does not exist in the store

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

I am having a problem with EF Core 3.x and One-To-Many navigation properties which I did not have in previous versions.

Consider the following code:

```
public class Book
{

    public Book()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Authors = new List<Author>();
    }

    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    public void AddAuthor(Author author)
    {
        author.BookId = this.Id;
        this.Authors.Add(author);
    }

}

public class Author
{

    public Author()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual Guid BookId { get; set; }

    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }

}
```

In previous EF version (such as 2.2), the following could be done:

```
var book = new Book();
context.Books.Add(book);
context.SaveChanges();
book = context.Books.First();
var author = new Author();
book.Authors.Add(author);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Now, the same code, after updating to EF Core 3.x, throws the following exception at the last SaveChanges() call, and I really can't figure out why:

**'Attempted to update or delete an entity that does not exist in the store.'**

If I check the DbContext's ChangeTracker, I indeed see that the Author entity is marked as Modified instead of Added.

The following, however, works fine:

```
  var book = new Book();
  context.Books.Add(book);
  context.SaveChanges();
  book = context.Books.First();
  var author = new Author() { BookId = book.Id };
  context.Authors.Add(author);
  context.SaveChanges();
```

What is happening? I read about possibly breaking changes in 3.x, but did not find the mention/solution to this problem. Anyone has an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask], especially the part labeled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem". The current title is not terribly illuminating.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry about that. I Just added a bit more specific title. If you have better suggestions, don't hesitate and I'll update it ASAP

Comment: Generally, anything that's in the tags, we don't need in the title. So the bit about Entity Framework is redundant. It looks like you're asking about a specific exception that comes up now that you've upgraded -- perhaps that is a better summary of the problem?

Comment: Can you please share your DbContext configuration, i.e., mappings, etc.

Comment: @JamesMcKeon I had not set any config in the DbContext, for the sake of the example. I solved it, anyways, as my answer bellow demonstrates. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, crawling on google further made me land on this post:
[Owned Entity marked as detached when adding to a collection when the entities primary key is set](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18055#issuecomment-545678535)

It appears to be a bug, that I could solve by using the following entity configuration, as **ajcvickers** suggested in the post linked above:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
```

Comment: Official breaking change: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#dc